# App engine can't invoke google cloud function

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, roles

I deployed a cloud function and I'm using a nodejs app running on an app engine to access it.

1. I've added the app engine default service account to my cloud function with the role 'cloud invoker'
2. I've added the cloud invoker role to my default service account for the app engine
3. The app engine and cloud function are located in the SAME project

What am I missing to be able to call my cloud function from inside my nodejs app? According to the docs, everything is fine.

p.s. giving AllUsers the cloud invoker role does actually work so the cloud function is fine, it's just the app engine service account that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the Cloud Functions Invoker role you don't add it to the service account, you add it to the receiving function

```
    gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding YOUR-FUNCTION-NAME \
        --member=serviceAccount:SVC-ACT-NAME@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
        --role= roles/cloudfunctions.invoker \
        --region=YOUR-REGION
```

Then when calling the Cloud Function from App Engine, you need to pass the bearer token
[See this link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-bearer-token)

Comment: I did, in the permissions tab of the cloud function I added the default app engine service account with the cloud function invoker role. Didn’t work though

Comment: How haven't specified what the error is or the code you are using. So next question is are you passing the bearer token when you inoke the Cloud Function?

Comment: I added a link in the answer to the documentation on making authenticated calls to Cloud Functions

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but I get a 403 forbidden error when attempting to fetch an id token. 

Url is set to the cloud function url and so is targetaudience.

Comment: Please add the actual code and commands you are using when you see the error